# AngularJS hover effect on change background color with dynamic color code

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to have hover effect on a div to change the color based on the color code I passed to. My idea is to pass color code to a directive and then call `element.css()`. However, I also need to add the hover class to the particular div using`element.addClass(hoverclass)`. Now, I got stuck because I don't know how to approach this.

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="social in socialArray">{{social.name}}</div>
```

this will give me somthing like:

```
<div>Facebook</div>
<div>Flickr</div>
<div>Google+</div>
<div>Instagram</div>
<div>Linkedin</div>
```

And my JS file:

```
$scope.socialArray = [
     {name:"Facebook", color:"#3B5998"}, 
     {name:"Flickr",color:"#FE0883"}, 
     {name:"Google+",color:"#C63D2D"}, 
     {name:"Instragram",color:"#4E433C"},    
     {name:"Linkedin",color:"#4875B4"}
];
```

My css:

```
.change-color{
  transition: 0.4s all;
}

.change-color:hover, .change-color:focus, .change-color:active{
  color: #fff;
  background-color:  #e38d13;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I want to be able to change the background-color dynamically based on the color I have in the socailArray. Any suggestion or hint will be awesome. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researched a while, I got it work by making a directive binding with colorcode.
Angular JS directive:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .directive('changeBackground', ['$animate', function ($animate) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
          colorcode: '@?'
      },
      link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
          element.on('mouseenter', function () {
              element.addClass('change-color');
              element.css('background-color', $scope.colorcode);
          });
          element.on('mouseleave', function () {
              element.removeClass('change-color');
              element.css('background-color', '#fff');
          });
      }
    };
}]);
```

And in the HTML file will look like this:

```
<div change-background colorcode="{{social.color}}" ng-repeat="social in socialArray">{{social.name}}</div>
```

I made a JSFIDDLE [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16148/)

Answer (score 9):

As an update to [@Shaohao Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5045744/shaohao-lin) answer, if you want to use the change color locally without creating a directive, you can do it in the template without writing aditional code in the controller or in directive.

```
<div 
            class="social-container change-color" 
            ng-repeat="social in socialArray" 
            ng-mouseover="hoverActive=true"
            ng-mouseleave="hoverActive=false"
            ng-style="hoverActive ? {'background-color':social.color} : {}">{{social.name}}</div>
```

here is JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zmskrf6y/1/

Comment: Interesting, nice.

Comment: This works fine. This should be the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came with a little bit different approach. It is based on the idea to dynamically append rules for every element.

```
myApp.directive("hoverColor", hoverColor);

function hoverColor(){
    function link(scope, element, attrs){
        //create dynamic css class name using angular's $id
        var dynamicClass = "hover-color-"+scope.$id,
        rules = [
        "color: #fff;",
        "background-color:  "+attrs.hoverColor+";",
        "cursor: pointer;"
        ].join(""),
        selector = [
        "."+dynamicClass+":hover",
        "."+dynamicClass+":focus",
        "."+dynamicClass+":active"
        ].join(", ");

        addCSSRule(selector, rules);

        element.addClass("hover-color " + dynamicClass);
    }

    //some browsers support addRule other insertRule so we need wrapping function
    function addCSSRule(selector, rules) {
          if("insertRule" in hoverColor.sheet) {
                hoverColor.sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}", 0);
          } else if("addRule" in sheet) {
                hoverColor.sheet.addRule(selector, rules, 0);
          }
    }

    //create new stylesheet and save reference to it
    hoverColor.sheet = (function() { 
         var style = document.createElement("style");
         // WebKit hack :(
         style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
         document.head.appendChild(style);
         return style.sheet;
    })();

    //add base rule, you could also add it to css stylesheet
    addCSSRule(".hover-color", "transition: 0.4s all;");

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    }

}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
<div hover-color="{{social.color}}" ng-repeat="social in socialArray">{{social.name}}</div>
```

Tested on Chrome and FF. [Try it on fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/334/)